# Is there a way to use MS TFS with SAP cloud plattform / WEB IDE?

Tags: tfs, sap-web-ide

SAP provides a git repository in the SAP cloud plattform to be used with SAP WEB IDE. But is there a way to use a client side Team Foundation Server (TFS) (behind a firewall) and without git as the version control system in WEB IDE?

If not, anyone tried to sync a git repo (SAP cloud) with the git repo if used as TFS backend automatically?

Answer (score 0):

Presently there is no out of box connector for TFS-SAP integration. There has been a related uservoice, you could vote it to get more attention.

> **Integrate TFS with SAP Solutions Manager**
>
> https://visualstudio.uservoice.com/forums/330519-team-services/suggestions/3243404-integrate-tfs-with-sap-solutions-manager

As for syncing git repo between tfs and sap automatically, there is no this tool or plug-in. You may need do this with the help of git command,local git repo, pull from one and push to another. It's also be able to directly build [external git remote repository](https://www.visualstudio.com/en-us/docs/build/define/repository#external-git-remote-repository) in TFS.

Answer (score 0):

At present WEBIDE can be only integrated with git available in SAP Cloud Platform as source control.